# Primng Dropdown show object Object instead of name

Tags: angular, primeng

I am using Primng and dropdown fetch data from API but show object object instead of projectName.
HTML codes are

```
<p-dropdown 
[options]="projects" 
[(ngModel)]="selectedProject"
 name="selectedProject" 
placeholder="select a Project"
optionLable="projectName" 
(onChange)="onChange($event)"
></p-dropdown>
```

and in Ts file  codes are

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { DBconnectionService } from '../dbconnection.service';
import { ProjectModel } from '../project-model';
import { PrimeNGConfig } from 'primeng/api';
import { EmployeeModel } from '../employee-model';



@Component({
  selector: 'app-assignments',
  templateUrl: './assignments.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./assignments.component.css']
})
export class AssignmentsComponent implements OnInit {


  employees: EmployeeModel[];
  projects: ProjectModel[];
  selectedProject: ProjectModel;


  constructor(private Service:  DBconnectionService, private primengConfig: PrimeNGConfig) {
    this.Service.getEmployee().toPromise().then(data => this.employees =data);
    this.Service.getproject().toPromise().then(data =>
      {
      this.projects = data;
    });
   }
```

Please tell me what I did wrong. ?

Comment: can you add console log of data/projects after fetching?

Comment: Yes, It fetch the data and there are no error in console. I have tried to add Json data and it shows. The pick list linked with this dropdown is also show the employees data. which is linked with selected project. Just not show the name or id of the dropdown item.

Comment: i mean you can put a short data in description then others can try reproduce and see any abnormal points

Comment: Can you show us the onChange($event) method

Comment: Hi, I manage to fix it. The problem was optionLabel="Name". I wrote the it as opetionLable instad of optionLabel.

Answer (score 0):

I started using PrimeNG with Angular 4.  Early on I had the same problem and I was advised to use SelectItem.  I originally then created the following static helper snippet.

````
import { TreeNode, SelectItem } from 'primeng/api';
import { Tree } from 'primeng/tree';
import { Table } from 'primeng/table';
/**
** Class of static helper methods for PrimeNG library
*/
export class _PCOMMON {

    ...

    /**
    ** Create the navigation list-box/dropdown data.
    **
    ** @typeParam T input array class.
    ** @parm an array of type `T`
    ** @parm fun method/anonymous to translate `T` to SelectItem
    ** @returns array of SelectItem (PrimeNG interface)
    ** @example
    ** Example (create data for company drowdown or listbox):
    ** ```typescript
    ** companies: SelectItem[] = _PCOMMON.createSelectItem<Company>(this.CompanyData,
    **  (item => ({ label:item.CompanyShortName, value:item.CompanyId })) )
    ** ```
    */
    public static createSelectItem<T>( data: T[], fun: CreateSelectItem<T> ): SelectItem[] {
        if( data.length > 0 ) {
            return data.map( fun );
        }
        return [];
    }
    //
}
````

A jasmine test is as follows show how to use it (in this test the input data is of TreeNode type):

```
    it('createSelectItem, should handle empty array ...', ( ) => {
        // given / when
        const items: SelectItem[] =
            _PCOMMON.createSelectItem<TreeNode>( [],
                (item => ({ label:item.label, value:item.key }) ) );
        // then
        expect( items.length ).toEqual( 0 );
    });
```

I have more recently changed my approach to the solution so I could string together the processing of the data as follows:

```
    createClassesDropdown( ): SelectItem[] {
        // CreateSelectItemArray found in _PCOMMON
        return this.companyvehicleData.classes.filter( act => act.Active === true )
            .sort( (a, b) => (a.SortOrder > b.SortOrder ? 1 : -1) )
            .CreateSelectItemArray( (item: IVehicleClass) => ({ label: `${item.VehicleClassType} (${item.VehicleClassId})`, value: item.VehicleClassId }));
    }
```

The implementation is as follows:

````
import { TreeNode, SelectItem } from 'primeng/api';
import { Tree } from 'primeng/tree';
import { Table } from 'primeng/table';
// for createSelectItem method
type CreateSelectItem<T> = (c: T) => SelectItem;
// Create extention methods
declare global {  
    interface Array<T> {
        CreateSelectItemArray(fun: CreateSelectItem<T>): SelectItem[];
    }
}
if ( !Array.prototype.CreateSelectItemArray ) {
    /**
    ** Extend the Array prototype to create a SelectItem for
    ** listBox, dropDown, etc controls.
    ** @typeParam T input array class.
    ** @parm fun method/anonymous to translate `T` to SelectItem
    ** @returns array of SelectItem (PrimeNG interface)
    ** @example
    ** ```typescript
    ** this.companyvehicleData.classes.filter( act => act.Active === true )
    **   .CreateSelectItemArray( (item: IVehicleClass) =>
    **     ({ label: `${item.VehicleClassType} (${item.VehicleClassId})`, value: item.VehicleClassId }));
    ** ```
    */
    Array.prototype.CreateSelectItemArray = function<T>( this: T[], fun: CreateSelectItem<T> ): SelectItem[] {
        return this.map( fun );
    }
}
````

The rendering of the dropdown is as follows:

```
    <p-dropdown id='VehicleClassId' name='VehicleClassId'
        [options]='classes'
        [style]="{'width':'250px'}" #VehicleClassId='ngModel'
        [(ngModel)]='model.VehicleClassId' placeholder='Select vehicle class...'
        >
    </p-dropdown>
```

As sample Jasmine test example is as follows:

```
    it('CreateSelectItemArray should filter and sort vehicle type class ...', fakeAsync(() => {
        // given / when
        const actual: SelectItem[] =
            [
                new VehicleClass( 1, 'v 1', 'v 1', 5 ),
                new VehicleClass( 2, 'v 2', 'v 2', 1 ),
                new VehicleClass( 3, 'v 3', 'v 3', 2 ),
                new VehicleClass( 4, 'v 4', 'v 4', 3 ),
                new VehicleClass( 5, 'v 5', 'v 5', 4 )
            ].CreateSelectItemArray( (item: IVehicleClass) => ({ label: `${item.VehicleClassType} (${item.VehicleClassId})`, value: item.VehicleClassId }));
        // then
        expect( actual.length ).toEqual( 5 ); // filter
        expect( actual[0].value ).toEqual( 1 );
        expect( actual[4].value ).toEqual( 5 );
        //
    }));
```